# Driver for windows XP on dell studio 1558 i3 processor

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, dell-studio, intel-core-i3

I have loaded Windows XP on my dell studio but now I don't have any drivers for Windows  should I do? I am not able to access net or switch on Bluetooth etc. I don't want to remove XP, I need it.

What should I do? Where can I get drivers for all my components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you don;t have the correct recovery disc - If you do use that.
I would go onto Dell's website from another computer. The Drivers download page is: http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/index.aspx?c=uk&cs=ukdhs1&l=en&s=dhs
You will be able to enter your service tag here to better match the drivers to your product.

Download at a bare minimum the correct networking driver for your PC, all of the drivers required if its practical. Transfer them over to your PC on a USB stick and install them and you should be good to go.

Comment: a quick search for the Studio 1558 @ Dell comes up with a laptop. Dell's site did not list any available windows XP drivers for it. If you run into the same issue using the service tag then you might check the website for the maker of the network adapters to see if they have XP drivers for the chipset. once you can get on to the internet there is a good chance that windows update would have drivers for the other hardware. if you are unable to find XP drivers for the networking hardware then you might try using a USB network adapter that is compatible with XP, just to get online.

Comment: @Xantec - Nice addition.